# In MySite site Settings option is not showing

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have clicked About Me as shown in the picture

[image]

then i have go to the option shown below in the picture but i cant find the Site Setting option?
[image]

can anybody help me out to the site setting option.

Comment: are you able to see this on home page?

Comment: yes i can see this on home page even when i click on Apps, site setting option is visible

Comment: Basically i want to add some pages on mysite and then deploy webparts on them ... it is adding pages but those are only visible to only me ... other user cant see those pages

Comment: Try going to the settings page directly using the url:

sef-qa/my/_layouts/15/settings.aspx

Comment: Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.

i got this error